# Dynamic horizontal progressbar width not showing full width in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am creating dynamic progressbar width but it's now showing properly. When i set width (272 dp ) in xml it's showing properly but i am setting same width programmetically it's not showing correct width.

XML:

```
<ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_sleep"
                            style="@style/SleepProgress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap" />
```

Code :

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) progressBarList.get(2).getLayoutParams();
params.width = 272;
        progressBarList.get(2).setLayoutParams(params);
        progressBarList.get(2).invalidate();
```

Comment: because params.width=272 is in pixels. and in xml you are setting dp values

Comment: @DivyeshPatel what shall i do for getting exactly?

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
progressWidth= convertDpToPixels(272, this);

 public int convertDpToPixels(float Dp, Context context) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, Dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Another formula:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        return Math.round(px);
}
```

Comment: COMPLEX_UNIT_DP not available shall i use DIP

Comment: change it with DIP